# How to open multiple Accordion tabs in react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to open multiple Accordion if possible. Currently using `react-bootstrap` library.

Following is my implementation :

```
<Accordion>
  {data.rows.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Card
        style={{
          border: "none",
          marginTop: "1em",
          borderBottom: "1px solid #f1f1f1",
        }}
      >
        <Card.Header
          style={{ background: "transparent", padding: "0.75em 0" }}
        >
          <Row>
            <Col lg="10" sm xs="9" style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
              <p
                className="cardtitle"
                style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}
              >
                {item.title}
              </p>
            </Col>
            <Col style={{ textAlign: "right" }} xs sm>
              {" "}
              <ContextAwareToggle eventKey={index}>
                +
              </ContextAwareToggle>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={index}>
          <Card.Body>
            <p className="cardcontent">{item.content}</p>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    );
  })}{" "}
</Accordion>

...


function ContextAwareToggle({ children, eventKey, callback }) {
  const currentEventKey = useContext(Fifth);

  const decoratedOnClick = useAccordionToggle(
    eventKey,
    () => callback && callback(eventKey)
  );

  const isCurrentEventKey = currentEventKey === eventKey;
  console.log(currentEventKey);
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className="accordianButton"
      // style={{ backgroundColor: isCurrentEventKey ? "pink" : "lavender" }}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        fontSize: "1.8em",
        fonWeight: "700",
        border: "transparent",
        color: "green",
      }}
      onClick={decoratedOnClick}
    >
      {isCurrentEventKey ? "-" : "+"}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Following is the link where I got my reference of code: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/

Also, if not accordion then please suggest any other component. Been trying to create a FAQ template in my project.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use an accordion for that, it's specifically designed to only show one card at once. Instead, you'd probably want to make each of your card components toggle on their own when clicked.

Answer (score 13):

The Accordion component is designed to expand one card at once. To achieve the effect of multiple tabs opened, you need to use multiple Accordions like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Accordion, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const tabs = [
  { id: 1, label: "Tab 1", description: "Content of Tab 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "Tab 2", description: "Content of Tab 2" },
  { id: 3, label: "Tab 3", description: "Content of Tab 3" }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {tabs.map(tab => (
        <Accordion key={tab.id} defaultActiveKey={tab.id}>
          <Card>
            <Card.Header>
              <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={tab.id}>
                {tab.label}
              </Accordion.Toggle>
            </Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={tab.id}>
              <Card.Body>{tab.description}</Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-multiple-accordion-tabs-oboks

Comment: thx. In order to reproduce the original look, I wrapped my accordions in a `<Card>` and added the `flush` attribute to each accordion (ie `<Accordion flush>`).

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**

It is now possible to keep accordion tabs open when opening another tab. This can be achieved using the `alwaysOpen` property:

```
               <Accordion alwaysOpen>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
                        <Accordion.Header>
                            Title
                        </Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                             Test Body
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="2">
                        <Accordion.Header>
                            Title
                        </Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                             Test Body
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                </Accordion>
```

[***Documentation here***](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/#always-open)

Comment: The documentation link is broken. Here is the correct one: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/accordion/#always-open

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the similar issue in my application. Due to inherent nature of accordion it is not possible to keep previous tab open while opening other tab.
Finally I created multiple accordion for each individual tab using a loop as below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Accordion, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class ItemsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const items = this.props.itemList;
        return (<div>
            {items.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <Accordion key={item.itemNumber} id={item.itemNumber}>
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Header>
                                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button}
                                    variant="link"
                                    eventKey={item.itemNumber}>
                                </Accordion.Toggle>
                                {item.itemName}
                            </Card.Header>
                            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={item.itemNumber}>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    {item.itemDescription}
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Accordion.Collapse>
                        </Card>
                    </Accordion>
                );
            })}
        </div>);
    }
    export default ItemsList;
```

It works perfectly fine and I am able to achieve behaviour of keeping two or more tabs open at the same time which is not possible using a single Accordion. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example of this? - @sapan prajapati

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem aswell, i solved it by using **reactstrap** library's **UncontrolledAccordion**

here is an example:

```
// ** Reactstrap Imports
import {
  UncontrolledAccordion,
  AccordionBody,
  AccordionHeader,
  AccordionItem,
  Label
} from "reactstrap";

// ** Example Component layout in the render() function
<UncontrolledAccordion stayOpen style={{ border: "none", width: "95%" }}>
  <Label>ACCORDION MENU</Label>
  <AccordionItem>
    <AccordionHeader targetId="1">Test 1</AccordionHeader>
    <AccordionBody accordionId="date">
        <Label className="form-label" for="default-picker">
          Test 1
        </Label>
    </AccordionBody>
  </AccordionItem>
  <AccordionItem>
    <AccordionHeader targetId="2">Test 2</AccordionHeader>
    <AccordionBody accordionId="date">
        <Label className="form-label" for="default-picker">
          Test 2
        </Label>
    </AccordionBody>
  </AccordionItem>
  <AccordionItem>
    <AccordionHeader targetId="3">Test 3</AccordionHeader>
    <AccordionBody accordionId="date">
        <Label className="form-label" for="default-picker">
          Test 3
        </Label>
    </AccordionBody>
  </AccordionItem>
</UncontrolledAccordion>
```

**Note:** you cannot control the state of the accordion items with an accordion like this, the user either needs to refresh the page or close the accordion items themselves.

Answer (score -1):

I achieved this by using a for loop on getElementsByClassName. Don't forget to bind this in the constructor of your component or it will not work.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.showAllAccordionTabs = this.showAllAccordionTabs.bind(this)
  }

  showAllAccordionTabs() {
    const getCollapsedAccordionSections = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "collapse"
    )
    for (var i = 0; i < getCollapsedAccordionSections.length; i++) {
      getCollapsedAccordionSections[i].classList.add("show")
    }
  }
```

Then add the onClick event

```
onClick={this.showAllAccordionTabs}
```